# Algoritmos e programação

Tags: algoritmo

O que preciso aprender antes de ir para as matérias?

Comment: Apesar de ser uma pergunta bacana, o contexto não se aplica aos padrões da rede SOpt, sem contar que e muito ampla.....

Comment: Pega uma aula de algorítimo no YouTube, se não me engano, o Gustavo Guanabara tem uns bons (só procura esse nome). Só por curiosidade, vc tem quantos anos?

Comment: A pergunta está fora do escopo da comunidade, o Stack Overflow é para aqueles que têm problema seja com um código ou outra coisa. Mas dá uma olhada no canal "Curso em Vídeo" no YouTube, e comece com o portugol para entender melhor as linguagens..

Comment: Comece fazendo programas, se realmente sentir que gosta disso e seus programas são bem considerados pelos usuários, aí você se preocupa em obter conhecimento de base para se profissionalizar.

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem vontade de aprender sobre como é programar aplicativos ou mesmo páginas da internet, já é um bom começo. Existe uma série de opções gratuitas que podem ensinar os primeiros passos.
Um deles  seria  o [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) que ensina desde `html`, `css`, `javaScript` e alguns conceitos de `PHP`, `XML` e `SQL`.

Mas é bom começar pelo `html` e depois ir conhecendo o `CSS`.
Nesse site você pode aprender online e testar seus próprios códigos depois de analisar as lições aprendidas.

Também pode aprender a programar através de videos da [universidade XTI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZDzuve7kho&list=PLxQNfKs8YwvGhXHbHtxtoB-tRRv6r3Rlr)

Através desses videos ela consegue te ensinar desde o principio até um nível bem avançado com aulas bem elaboradas.

Também você pode ler as apostilas da [Caelum para programação orientada a objetos](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/) em  java

Não podia deixar de indicar que antes de aprender uma linguagem orientada a objetos é bom você aprender a programação estruturada que é  uma disciplina de desenvolvimento de algoritmos, independentemente da sua complexidade e da linguagem de programação na qual será codificado, que facilita a compreensão da solução através de um número restrito de mecanismos de codificação.

Você vai aprender os tipos usados para  criar as variáveis e resolver problemas matemáticos.

- Vai criar comandos condicionais
- Vai aprender os comandos de repetição
- A criar funções
- E muito mais...

Para a programação estruturada escolha `C`,também existe o `Pascal`. Uma vez escolhida a linguagem você baixa  uma `IDE` para criar e compilar seus próprios algoritmos!

Ai sim depois disso pode aprender a Programação Orientada a Objetos.

Comment: Você viu como o pessoal vota em coisa ruim também? Você ganhou 5 votos em uma resposta que não é uma resposta. É a sua opinião. Eu poderia dizer que a W3Schools ensina fazer tudo errado e as apostilas da Caelum é cheia de erros e que o vídeo dificilmente ensina alguma coisa. Além disso só com essas coisas não ajuda de fato ele. Poderia dizer ainda que C não é a linguagem para ele começar aprender procedural, muito menos Java para OOP. Mas não vou dizer para não iniciar uma discussão, que é tudo o que não desejamos aqui, textos opinativos.

Comment: Obrigado pela edição @MarceloBonifazio. Agora ficou bem mais interessante sem aqueles links e tudo  mais, eu devia ter feito como você!!